# MySQL: Delete all rows older than 10 minutes

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have a timestamp field in my table. How do I delete records older than 10 minutes old?

Tried this:

```
DELETE FROM locks WHERE time_created < DATE_SUB( CURRENT_TIME(), INTERVAL 10 MINUTE)
```

Didn't work. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: I used this code:

```
SELECT time_created, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, TIMESTAMPDIFF( MINUTE, time_created, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ) FROM locks
```

But oddly, this gives the wrong result too

```
time_created         CURRENT_TIMESTAMP      TIMESTAMPDIFF( MINUTE, time_created,     CURRENT_TIMESTAMP )
2010-08-01 11:22:29   2010-08-08 12:00:48   10118
2010-08-01 11:23:03   2010-08-08 12:00:48   10117
```

Comment: What are the types of your fields?

Comment: id [int(11)], time_created[timestamp]

Comment: Does `SELECT DATE_SUB( CURRENT_TIME(), INTERVAL 10 MINUTE)` return what you expect? If not, check the server time.

Comment: @Oden: 11:55:51, `SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` gives 2010-08-08 11:56:25 but `TIMEDIFF( CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, time_created )` gives a wrong number as well.

Comment: What is wrong with you last example? There are 7 days and 37-38 minutes between the timestamps given. That amounts to 10117-10118 minutes...

Comment: @Ivar, you're right. One of our admin's been messing with the system date for some reason. Crap!

Answer (score 164, accepted):

If time_created is a unix timestamp (int), you should be able to use something like this:

```
DELETE FROM locks WHERE time_created < (UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - 600);
```

(600 seconds = 10 minutes - obviously)

Otherwise (if time_created is mysql timestamp), you could try this:

```
DELETE FROM locks WHERE time_created < (NOW() - INTERVAL 10 MINUTE)
```

Comment: Not sure if that works right, UNIX_TIMESTAMP() outputs number, i guess in milliseconds and the time_create[timestamp] field shows time as 2010-08-01 11:22:29

Comment: Hmm... Try `SELECT time_created, (NOW() - INTERVAL 10 MINUTE), DATE_SUB( CURRENT_TIME(), INTERVAL 10 MINUTE) from locks;` Does any of them provide compareable results? In my experience the middle one will give you a mysql timestamp, while the last one returns `NULL`.

Comment: Very much appreciated.

Answer (score 32):

The answer is right in the [MYSQL manual itself](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_adddate).

```
"DELETE FROM `table_name` WHERE `time_col` < ADDDATE(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 HOUR)"
```

Comment: A similar answer is on top with the right quantity and with an alternative. Guess correct and best answer are different

Comment: "INTERVAL -1HOUR" should be "INTERVAL -1 HOUR"