# How to get rows older than 30 min

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table with column time which remembers the time of the row.

So my question is how to get rows where time is older than 30 minutes ?

I have red some threads but I get errors. I have tried these, but none of them works...

```
SELECT * from temp WHERE to_timestamp(insert_date) < NOW() - INTERVAL '30 minutes' 

SELECT * FROM temp WHERE insert_date < NOW() - INTERVAL '30 minutes';
```

Comment: SELECT * FROM temp WHERE insert_date < NOW() - INTERVAL 30 MINUTE;

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM temp WHERE `timestamp` < (NOW() - INTERVAL 30 MINUTE);
```

You could take it from just replacing Delete with Select :)

[MySQL Delete Records Older Than X Minutes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11252704/mysql-delete-records-older-than-x-minutes)

[MySQL: Delete all rows older than 10 minutes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3433465/mysql-delete-all-rows-older-than-10-minutes)

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT * FROM temp 
WHERE insert_date < date_sub(now(), interval 30 minute)
```